# Swift 3 - didSet for the opposite direction?

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, properties, didset

Let's say I have these two classes :

```
class A {}
class B{
   var myA:A?
}
```

I want to know when that happens:

```
let b = B()
let a = A()

b.myA = a    // <<<---- I want to observe this from my A class
```

I would also like to know who is the owner(In this case, `b`).

Sort of like a `didSetSelfAsAProperty(ofOwner:AnyObject).`

What I am trying to achieve:
We have MVVM architecture in our project. I noticed that I need to set both directions when initializing an instance of a view model/view.I need to tell the view model who's its view and vice versa.

Any ideas?

Comment: You want to find out when a property is observed and what observed it?

Comment: As I I mentioned, I want to observe on my class when it is set as a property of another class + get the owner.

Comment: You should probably in your `didSet` logic call a function in `A` to notify it. There's no automatic way to do what you want.

Comment: @sschale I know that this is an option. I am looking for a solution where I wont need to override didSet in each and every class that has A as a property.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're looking for the Observer Pattern. You could achieve it with either callbacks, KVO or third party libraries.